# BeagleBone Black PRU examples do not halt

Tags: arm, embedded, beagleboneblack, texas-instruments

I have a Beaglebone Black Rev C. I downloaded the am335x_pru_package from https://github.com/beagleboard/am335x_pru_package and copied it over to my beaglebone. I was able to get the PRU_memAccessPRUDataRam example working, and then tried to develop my own application to open up UART2 and read from it. Long story short, I was having difficulties and wanted to start again with the baseline example. Now, the example no longer works, it hangs while waiting on a HALT for the PRU. I checked the other example and got the same result. I didn't change anything in the example code. What could have changed to make the examples hang there (seems like the PRU code is not finishing, but there are no jumps or branches, so is it just not running?)?

Thanks!